# How far is too far with escalating sexual content?

Tags: character-development, planning, sex, erotica

I am writing about a main character who begins the story as a virgin, and over the course of the story escalates her sexual behavior from 1 on 1 heterosexual sex to prostitution and then to what might be described as some more extreme, potentially risky sexual practises.

However, I am wondering how far is too far?  How far can the story go before turning the titillating into a turn-off?

For example, the MC, as a prostitute with some magical abilities, has the opportunity to help a client with some taboo fantasies (sexualised cannibalism in this case) experience his fantasies without anyone actually being hurt, in a manner similar to a hyper-real VR that affects all the senses. As to why she might help such a person with such a fantasy, it's because doing so is (for her) no more difficult than helping any other client, and her goal is not to facilitate a present or future criminal act but to safely defuse it by making the (fake) reality not live up to the client's fantasy.

However, while this follows the MC's trend of ever more extreme sexual practises, would this (and other taboo fantasies that other potential clients might have) be a step too far?

By "A step too far", I mean that the content that may be titillating to some - mostly those with the fetish described - would be a turn-off to a large number of potential readers.

[Describing sex in a non-erotic fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42401/describing-sex-in-a-non-erotic-fiction) is *not* a duplicate of this question... my work would be considered erotic fiction, and there are most certainly no 'fade to black' moments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Describing sex in a non-erotic fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42401/describing-sex-in-a-non-erotic-fiction)

Comment: @ArcanistLupus No.  It doesn't,  at all.  I most definitely *don't* have a fade-to-black.

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by 'a step too far'? As it is stated it is largely opinion-based.

Comment: @wetcircuit I beg to differ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_cannibalism --- maybe not what the OP was referring to, but it does exist

Comment: You tagged this question as 'Character Development'. My comments are about character. Read **120 Days of Sodom** – the real pitfall is in boring readers with a laundry list of transgressive acts that have no connection to plot or characters (no stakes). Pornographic writing does not need to aspire to anything literary, and it tends to look ridiculous when it tries (**50 Shades**, et al).

Comment: There's an audience for everything. What is *your* target audience? On what kind of platform do you intend to publish your story?

Comment: Just a reminder that this question/subject may not be your cup of tea, so your options are: 1) Ignore it or 2) gentle redirection (like a teaching moment). Let's keep it civil, thanks!

Comment: This is far too far in the realm of opinion and particular circumstances; no general rule can be given. Many internal and external factors such as context, treatment, stylistic approach, artistic merit, morality, audience expectation, genre, readership, and the identity of the author will affect how the audience responds. Certainly nobody can make an authoritative statement like "sex with a live dog is ok, sex with a dead dog is beyond the pale". Just write and if there's an audience, maybe you'll find it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer to this question is ineffable. As with any subject of creative fiction, what can be shared is a function of how it is written (narrative voice, characterization, tone, and author intent) . It is as if the OP wants to know how far they can push "the bounds" when the OP needs to just focus on writing the work they want to write. Beta-readers and critique groups and agents can tell them if they were successful or not

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing erotic fiction, then you need to consider your audience. For some, they have no boundaries and are more than eager to see more of your work. Most are not going to be into more taboo fantasies, particularly sexual cannibalism. If you are going too far for a conventional audience, then this idea you have may not be a good fit. Sexual cannibalism is a niche fetish all on its own, not to mention what else you may wish to add. If you are writing about sexual taboos, expect the large majority to be turned off. If you want to please the masses, write about vanilla sex.